# Generating database uniqueId in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need to generate a uniqueID for every user that registers on nodeJS app.

I use Sequelize and i've created an infinite loop until the uniqueID is generated.

If i use the following code:

```
var breakLoop=false;
db.Contact.create({ first_name: req.body.first_name, last_name: req.body.last_name,
    phone:req.body.phone, email:req.body.email, id_domain: req.body.id_domain }).
 then( async function (item) {
    while(!breakLoop) {
        var coupon=Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5);
        let found=await db.Coupon.findOne({ where: {coupon:coupon}});
        if(!found) {
            db.Coupon.create({ coupon: coupon, id_contact: item.id }).then(function (item) {
                session.coupon=coupon;
                return breakLoop=true;
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            });
        }   
    }
    res.json({item:item.id});
});
```

i generate 2-3 coupons for every user; i know i could make a stored proc for this, but i would like to use the correct use case in Node; may be i have to use a Promise but i do not how to use it in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of `await` with try and catch block to understand the flow easier.

```
var breakLoop = false;
db.Contact.create({
  first_name: req.body.first_name, last_name: req.body.last_name,
  phone: req.body.phone, email: req.body.email, id_domain: req.body.id_domain
}).
  then(async function (item) {
    while (!breakLoop) {
      try{
        var coupon = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5);
        let found = await db.Coupon.findOne({ where: { coupon: coupon } });
        if (!found) {
          try{
            let newCoupon = await db.Coupon.create({ coupon: coupon, id_contact: item.id });
            session.coupon = newCoupon;
            breakLoop = true;
            // you can also use break; to exit from the loop
          }catch(error){
            console.log("Error in creating new coupon " + error);
            breakLoop = true;
            // you can also use break; to exit from the loop
          }
        }
      }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        breakLoop = true;
        // you can also use break; to exit from the loop
      }
    }
    res.json({ item: item.id });
  });
```